# multiple draggable spans don't overlap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, draggable, collision

i'm trying to make multiple spans draggable but the only problem is that, they overlap each other. but i want to make them collide each other instead of overlapping.

```js
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  cursor: "crosshair",
  containment: "#insideme"
});
```

```css
#insideme {
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px dotted red;
}
.selector {
      background: lime;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border: 1px solid drakgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="insideme">
<div class="selector">Drag me</div>
<div class="selector">Drag me</div>
<div class="selector">Drag me</div>
<div class="selector">Drag me</div>
<div class="selector">Drag me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `sortable` on it

```js
$( "#insideme" ).sortable({
  cursor: "crosshair",
  containment: "#insideme"
});
```

```css
#insideme {
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px dotted red;
}
.selector {
      background: lime;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border: 1px solid drakgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="insideme">
<div class="selector">Drag me</div>
<div class="selector">Drag me</div>
<div class="selector">Drag me</div>
<div class="selector">Drag me</div>
<div class="selector">Drag me</div>
</div>
```

`sortable` basically only swap their position, it can't let blocks stay anywhere you want.

So you want drag these blocks everywhere and collide each other at same time,
this lib [gridstack.js](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js) may help you achieve that.

Check this [demo](http://gridstackjs.com/demo/float.html)